# vscode Nest snippet choices and add tab stops to choices

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I want to do something like that in my snippets for visual studio code:

`"V.G.${1|BLOCK_NR,MASS_MM,MASS_360,I,J,K,R,FEEDRATE,FEEDRATE_SCALE,MERR[${2}]|}"`
So after choose the option MERR[] I will see the cursor inside the brackets.

and how i have to manage sub choices like:

`"V.G.${1|choice${2|subchoiceA,subchoiceB|},choice, choice......}"`

If I choose MERR[] Option I will jump into [Cursor should be here]. How can i handle this?

Comment: Are you asking about the `subchoice` snippet too?  I have a workaround for that, but in general the sniuppet grammar only allows plain text as choice options.

Comment: Yes i ask for subchoice too. what is your workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a workaround to your `subchoiceA/B` question because you cannot have anything except plain text as choices - no tabstops or subchoices, etc.  Your example:

```
V.G.${1|choice${2|subchoiceA,subchoiceB|},choice, choice......}"
```

This can be achieved however with 2 snippets:

```
"choices with subchoices": {
  "prefix": "_choices",   // whatever prefix you want    
  "body": [
    "V.G.${1|choice1, _subchoices,choice2,choice3|}"
  ],    
  "description": "variables in a choice element"
},

"my subchoice list": {
  "prefix": "_subchoices",       // this prefix must be what you used in the main snippet
                                // as your subchoice option
  "body": [ "${1|subchoiceA,subchoiceB|}" ],
  "description": "subChoices"
},
```

What happens is that when you choose the `subchoices` option in the main snippet it will see it as the prefix for the second snippet - that is pretty neat.  But it will not do so until you trigger that recognition with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> the usual intellisense trigger and then <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the second snippet.

It is only one or two extra keystrokes to get subchoices working inside of a parent choice element when otherwise it can't be done at all.

The only issue is that your second prefix - here `subchoices` cannot be a continuation of another string with no spaces otherwise it won't be recognized as a standalone snippet prefix by vscode.  That is why I added the space before `subchoices` in the main snippet since your example has `"V.G.${1....}` with no space before the option would be inserted.

Here is a demo:

[image: snippet with subchoices]